# PHP User defined functions issue

Tags: php, mysqli

I can't figure out why I can't get the values of message sent $message_sent and mobile number $mobilenumber and store them in a db after sending the message using the grabdetails function as shown on my code below. Someone please guide me

//code

```
 // fetch values from a database
 $name = $resultarr['name'];
 $amount = $resultarr['amount'];
 $transaction_id = $resultarr['trans_id'];
 $date = $resultarr['time_paid'];

    //message template
    $message = "Dear $name we have received $amount from you. MPESA transaction Id $transaction_id on $date.";

    $mobilenumber = $resultarr['msisdn']; // get mobile number from array
    $message_sent = $message;


    $serviceArguments = array(
            "mobilenumber" => $mobilenumber,
            "message" => $message_sent
    );
      // send message through a web service
    $client = new SoapClient("http://52.34.63.16:8080/smsengine/smsws?WSDL");

    $result = $client->process($serviceArguments);

   // call function to grab mobile number and message
      grabdetails($message_sent, $mobilenumber);
    return $result;


 }

 // the function
 function grabdetails($messagee, $mobno)
   {

   $message_sent = $messagee;
  $mobilenumber = $mobno;


 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "smsdb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
// insert into db
$sql = "INSERT INTO smsdb (sms_text, receiver_number, time_sent)
   VALUES
    ('$message_sent', '$mobilenumber', CURDATE() )";
```

Comment: 1. Do you execute your sql-query `$sql`? 2. Do you know that `DATETIME` is a datatype? 3. Do you know that __nothing__ will be executed after `return` statement?

Comment: Hello there, I have edited the code Still not getting the values in a db... @u_mulder

Comment: I ask again - do you __execute__ your query?

Comment: I am not getting what you are saying.....the select or the insert one.? @u_mulder

Comment: I don't see any select queries here. So the question is about `insert` one.

Comment: Okay, I thought when I call this script.php file the insert statement will be executed also, no? @u_mulder

Comment: No, it won't unless you call something like `$conn->query($sql)`. But as you show just part of script I don;t know do you have this line or not.

Comment: Actually I didn't. Let me test it ....hoping every thing else is on point

Answer (score 0):

If you define something outside functions, you need to use "global" tag in order to use them inside functions. It basically means that you are using global variables inside functions.

In that case, all you have to is add

```
global $message_sent,$mobilenumber;
```

Comment: What global variables are you talking about?

Comment: Hello there, so if I use the global key word, when I want to insert their values in a db, will they have gotten the value say message_sent = "the message" and $mobilenumber = "377****"? @Mert